# Azure SSIS Package: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

> TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I'm getting the error above quite often (or so it feels to me) when running ETL, maintenance, and data cleaning tasks through SSIS packages on our azure hosted databases, sometimes with statements that only take about 1 minute to run. Data flow tasks are especially problematic. Is there some way to "whitelist" our server where these jobs run so the connection stays open? Or how can I make an ssis package retry a task with a new connection? Would that even work with a partially executed data flow task?

(There's no timeout specified in the connection properties, and RetainSameConnection is set to false so it doesn't try to hold on to the same connection for the entire package)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an ADO Connection for the destination connections, you can change the connection timeout settings from 30 to 600. For more information, please click [here](http://sqlconcept.com/2013/01/25/migrating-data-to-azure-error-0xc020844b-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/).

Try to send those tasks on batches to avoid long running tasks and excessive resource usage (throttling).

You can also try to scale up the tier of the SQL Azure database while running these SSIS packages only.